# R: How to count number of 1 and write to vector

Tags: r

I have as signal-vector that looks like this:

> a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)

I will count how often a 1 occurs in one raw and write that in to a vector b e.g. for vector a it should result in:

> b
>   5,2,1,1,1,1,3

The reason is that i will plot a histogram that shows me the distribution of the length of the events. Maybe there is already a function in R that does exactly that? Otherwise with if-loop?

Cheers 
Greg

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html

Comment: Is there some reason for not accepting one of those answers?

Answer (score 5):

You could try `rle` (Note that these solutions are also from `base R`)

```
with(rle(a), lengths[!!values])
#[1] 5 2 1 1 1 1 3
```

Or

```
unname(table(cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(a)))))[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
#[1] 5 2 1 1 1 1 3
```

If the vector is not binary

```
with(rle(a), lengths[values==1])
#[1] 5 2 1 1 1 1 3
```

Or

```
unname(table(cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(a==1)))))[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
```

#### EDIT

If the vector starts with numbers other than `1`.  For example `0` or `2` (as mentioned by @Ananda Mahto in the comments)

```
 a[1] <- 2
 a1 <- a[which(a==1)[1]:length(a)]
 unname(table(cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(a1==1)))))[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
 #[1] 4 2 1 1 1 1 3
 with(rle(a), lengths[values==1])
 #[1] 4 2 1 1 1 1 3
```

Or

```
with(rle(a == 1), lengths[values]) # from @Richard Scriven's comments
```

Comment: One other way `with(rle(a == 1), lengths[values])`

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks, perhaps one character less.

Comment: The `cumsum` approaches are dependent on the first value though, right?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks, you are right.  It depends on the first value

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug, but since you are only dealing with ones and zeroes, you could also use [`TrueSeq`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/TrueSeq.R) from my "SOfun" package ([only on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun)).

Here's what `TrueSeq` does:

```
library(SOfun)
TrueSeq(as.logical(a))
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7
```

Keeping that in mind, you can just use `tabulate` on the output since that would discard the zeroes:

```
tabulate(TrueSeq(as.logical(a)))
# [1] 5 2 1 1 1 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `base` R :

```
count1<-strsplit(paste(a,collapse=""),"0")[[1]]
b<-nchar(count1[count1!=""])

> b
[1] 5 2 1 1 1 1 3
```