# R: Count of consecutive numbers over array

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I am trying to find a maximum number of consecutive "1" over a third dimension of an array in R. The array consist of "0" and "1". Here is an example:

```
my_array <- array(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1), dim=c(2,2,5))
```

I tried to work with:

```
apply(my_array,c(1,2),rle)
```

but the result is not very straightforward, ideally, the resulting matrix should look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    2
[2,]    2    3
```

Is there any more sufficient function than rle() in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
apply(my_array,c(1,2),function(x){
                         max(rle(x)$length[rle(x)$values=="1"])
                       })

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    2
#[2,]    2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`TrueSeq`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/TrueSeq.R) from my "SOfun" package ([only on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun)), as also mentioned in my answer to a [surprisingly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222363/r-how-to-count-number-of-1-and-write-to-vector), you could do:

```
library(SOfun)
apply(my_array, c(1, 2), function(x) max(tabulate(TrueSeq(as.logical(x)))))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    2
# [2,]    2    3
```